# Hipchat Rooms History API

Tags: api, curl, hipchat

I'm running into issues with the HipChat API, I can't seem to get the [history endpoint](https://www.hipchat.com/docs/apiv2/method/view_room_history) to accept a payload so I can narrow down my searches. I'm using a personal access token, and while I can get results from a basic `/v2/room/{room_id}/history?auth_token=<auth>` curl I can't seem to get anything else to work. I've been testing with the `max-results` query parameter. I've tried a couple of different iterations, things along the lines of:

`/v2/room/{room_id}/history?auth_token=<auth>&max-results=10
/v2/room/{room_id}/history?max-results=10&auth_token=<auth>
/v2/room/{room_id}/history?reverse=false&max-results=10`

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25226181/how-to-get-all-message-history-from-hipchat-for-a-room-via-the-api) answer, but it doesn't work for me, and actually causes my terminal to crash. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you add more information on what errors you are getting? I tried your examples, and they worked correctly for me. Another thing to check is to make sure that your token has the correct scopes for the API you are calling (view_messages in this case)

Comment: Have you tried using the Auth token in a header rather than a query param? I have an integration and use it in that way to get the history from a room with a similar set of query params as you are using.